# Is the existence of absolutely separable quantum states possible in nature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

Can quantum systems be in an absolutely separable state, without any relationship? Or does this approximation and some measure of entanglement (for example, through gravitational interaction) still exist?

For example, if a pure state | ψ} ∈ H_1 ⊗ H_2 can be written as | ψ} = | ψ_1} ⊗ | ψ_2}, where | ψ_i} is a pure state of the ith subsystem, then this state is separable. Can the state of the subsystems be absolutely separable, with zero entanglement measure? Is this even possible in nature, or does some entanglement still exist?

Comment: It would be really great if you could elaborate on this by possibly providing an example.

Comment: If a pure state | ψ} ∈ H_1 ⊗ H_2 can be written as | ψ} = | ψ_1} ⊗ | ψ_2}, where | ψ_i} is a pure state of the ith subsystem, then this state is separable. Can the state of the subsystems be absolutely separable, with zero entanglement measure? Is this even possible in nature, or does some entanglement still exist?

Comment: how do you define "*absolutely separable*" here?

Comment: Do you think there is such a thing as the "wavefunction of the whole universe"?  If yes, how can you reconcile this with measurements? If no, how can you talk about pure states?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make a separate state that is not entangled at all. Just measure two independent spins, let us say the results are up and down, then you have the separable state $|\psi>=|u d>$.
A change of base will not entangle them, let us say you rotate it some angle and use a different base, the new state will be:$|\psi'>=|a_i r+b_il,c_i r+d_il > $, where l and r are left and right states. You can still see that the state is separable, and the results between the two spins are not correlated.

Comment: We are talking about complete separability in all possible bases.

Comment: I do not see how a change of base will mix left and right particles, but I might be missing something. Let me update the answer

Comment: Are you saying that absolutely isolated objects can exist in the universe?

Comment: May be I misunderstand your question. No, of course not, but it does not mean they must be entangled either

Comment: What does “not isolated” mean from the point of view of quantum mechanics?